# Unsure what to do with the CMake file from pigpio

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, pigpio

I am new to CMake and was hoping to use a pretty simple Raspberry Pi application as a learning experience. I have a few files in a simple directory structure, plus I'm using [pigpio](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio). My code compiles fine by itself, but when I use CMake to generate a makefile, the makefile cannot find the references in pigpio. pigpio includes a file, `Findpigpio.cmake`, in the `util` directory, so I tried including it in `CMakeLists.txt`, but to no avail.

File structure:

```
RPapp
├──inc/
|   ├──spi.h
|   └──gpio.h
├──src/
|   ├──spi.c
|   ├──gpio.c
|   └──main.c
├──pigpio/
|   ├──util/
|   |   ├──Findpigpio.cmake
|   |   └──[whatever else is in here]
|   └──[remainder of code cloned from github]
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(RPapp C)
include(pigpio/util/Findpigpio.cmake)
include_directories(inc)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(RPapp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/gpio.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spi.c)
```

I `mkdir _build`, `cd _build`, and `cmake ..`, which gives very promising output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found pigpio: /usr/local/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/RPapp/_build
```

but then when I run make, the output shows that it cannot reference the functions from pigpio:

```
Scanning dependencies of target RPapp
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/RPapp.dir/src/main.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/RPapp.dir/src/gpio.c.o
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/RPapp.dir/src/spi.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable RPapp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/RPapp.dir/src/main.c.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gpioTerminate'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/RPapp.dir/src/main.c.o: in function `buff_rdy_handler':
main.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `spiRead'
...(more of the same)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know about pigpio specifically. But from a pure cmake perspective you need to pull in the pigpio CMakeLists.txt and add that library as a link dependency. The `include(pigpio/util/Findpigpio.cmake)` is unnecessary.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(RPapp C)
# removed  following line
#include(pigpio/util/Findpigpio.cmake)
include_directories(inc)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(RPapp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/gpio.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spi.c)

# added these lines
add_subdirectory(pigpio)
target_link_libraries(RPapp pigpio)
```

Comment: According to pigpio's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), the target pigpio is not shipped with include directories (with `target_include_directories`). So they should be included manually in the main `CMakeLists.txt`: `include_directories(pigpio)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Could you help me see where you saw this in that file? I am not seeing how you discovered this :-/  Likewise, could you give an example of what you mean by "they chould be included in the main `CMakeLists.txt`"?  You mean I need a bunch of lines like `include_directories(pigpio/command.h  pigpio/pigpio.h  ...)`?  Sorry if these are easy questions, but I'm really struggling with the CMake paradigm right now.

Comment: @TrivialCase: Do you know what **include directories** means for a compiler? This term is not CMake-specific, but is applicable for every C and C++ compiler. In my previous comment I meant exactly what is written: `include_directories(pigpio)`.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, but you said "they" should be included, and had only the top level directory listed - I assumed the plurality of the comment indicated that you were leaving out something that was not obvious to me.  And when you say "according to pigpio's `CMakeLists`", you just meant that there is some directive you see is missing from that file, so you infer that this line is necessary?  Not that the pigpio `CMakeLists` specifically says that this is the case, right?

Comment: @kaylum It looks like this did the trick - or rather, now I have undefined references to `pthread` functions, but I guess I need to clone that project as well and try to figure out similar magic. However, now I'm more confused than ever about what that `.cmake` file is supposed to do and why it is included at all.

Comment: That `.cmake` is internal to the project. You don't really need to understand or use it. Just like you are not tasked to understand the rest of the code for the purposes of just building it.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks! I figured out many/most the things that had me confused.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer to my own question in case someone else is as misguided as I was. I should have been thinking about CMake more in terms of creating makefiles.  If you don't do this frequently, and are trying to learn CMake, I recommend trying to put together a manual makefile for your example project first, then going through the process. I'm not sure why I was trying to learn CMake as though it has no connections to makefiles... not useful.

@kaylum is correct in his response, but there were other things I was missing as well.  For starters, there was no point cloning pigpio into the file structure for the project - I already had it installed and could just link it as a library to the target.  Likewise, even when I got it to try to (unnecessarily) build pigpio at build time, I still was missing a couple of dependencies.  Anyway, here is one possible, simple `CMakeLists.txt` file that can do the job I was trying to do:

```
# RPapp/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(RPapp C)

find_package(Threads)

include_directories(inc)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -O2")

add_executable(RPapp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/gpio.c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spi.c)

target_link_libraries(RPapp pigpio rt)

install(TARGETS RPapp DESTINATION bin)
```